# Exposing data from oracle database for web-service use

Tags: json, oracle, rest, api, web-services

I've got a question related to oracle database and working with an API/web service to extract data from said database for use.

My experience in the area is limited so I'm hoping for some discussion here about it. My goal is to create a web service that has several fields and the should all fields submitted match an entry in the database, the program should return something positive, lets just say "true". If false, it will identify that there is a problem with the input.

My understanding right now is I can first use an API to expose the data, which I can then manipulate and query-check with a web service? Correct me if I am wrong with this general/overall plan. Moving on from this, if anyone have any relevant advice or programs that might prove to be useful here, but the main goal of posting this is to get a high-level understanding of the process.

Also, the plan is to use REST/JSON services here. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also not very skilled yet but if I correctly understand your question the answer could be [ORDS](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/rest-data-services/overview/index.html)

I found many essential informations [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/an-introduction-to-json-support-in-the-oracle-database)

With ORDS is possible to POST a request associated with a store procedure that do all the validations that the client can't do.

Comment: Hey there, I've been looking into this more since I posted the question and have also come across ORDS. It seems like the best solution to implement my app. Thanks for the links.